# Read Column from Excel File C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have method, which gets the cells from an excel File. The problem is that 'if (usedrange.Cells[1, j] != null)' gives an NullReference Exception. I used that Code at Work on Visual Studio, but now at home its not working. Can someone tell me why?

```
   public List<string> GetBrandListFromExcel(string path, int sheet)
    {
        var i = 1;
        var j = 1;

        List<string> zelle = new List<string>(); ;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
            Range usedrange = ws.UsedRange;

            for (j = 1; j <= 2250; j++)
            {
                if (usedrange.Cells[1, j] != null)
                {
                    var cell = usedrange.Cells[j, 1] as Range;
                    if (cell.Value2 != null)
                    {
                        zelle.Add((string)cell.Text);
                    }
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
            wb.Close();
        }
        return brands;
    }
```

Comment: Don't hardcode things, get the number of columns in the usedRange properly: `for (j = 1; j <= usedrange.Columns; j++)`

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I could see that the **usedRange** is created from different **Worksheet**  object (**ws1**) instead of correct one (**ws**). It might be the reason. Change it as below and check.

```
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
Range usedrange = ws.UsedRange;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i just tried things out and forgot to change it. I created the usedRange from the correct Worksheet and its still not working